# Graph where any two vertices have unique neighbor in common must be regular.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So, I was reading the first chapter of Van Lint's Course in Combinatorics and could not figure out this problem. Please help me and explain the solution in a simple manner.

[image: The question is in this pic]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G = (V,E)$ be our graph. For $x \in V$, let $N(x) := \{ y \in V \big| (x,y)\in E\}$ be the neighborhood of $x$.
The hypothesis reads : for all $x\neq y \in V$, $N(x) \cap N(y)$ has exactly one element.

**Question 1)** Let $x,y \in V$ be such that $(x,y)\notin E$.

Let $v\in V$ be the unique vertex belonging to $N(x) \cap N(y)$.
We have a function $f_{x,y} : N(x) \mapsto N(y)$ defined by :
$$f_{x,y}(n) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} v & \textrm{if } n=v\\ \textrm{the only vertex of } N(n) \cap N(y) & \textrm{if } n \neq v \end{matrix}\right.$$

**$f_{x,y}$ is injective**

Indeed, let $m\neq n \in N(x)$. If we had $f_{x,y}(n) = f_{x,y}(m)$, then $N(n)\cap N(m)$ would have at least two distinct elements, namely $x$ and $f_{x,y}(n)$, a contradiction to our hypothesis!

Since $f_{y,x}: N(y) \mapsto N(x)$ is also an injection, we must have $|N(x)|=|N(y)|$, qed.

**Question 2)**
We need to show that $|N(x)| = |N(y)|$ for all $x, y \in V$.

**(edit) the following isn't correct (how to find $z$?)**

> Let $x,y \in V$. If $(x,y) \notin E$, this follows from 1). Hence, we can assume that $x,y$ are connected. Since neither $x$ nor $y$ has degree $|V| - 1$, one can find $z \in V$ that is neither connected to $x$ nor to $y$. From 1), we get $|N(x)| = |N(z)| = |N(y)|$ qed.

**A correct proof (credits to bof)**
Take any $x_0 \in V$. Set $X := \{v \in V \big| d(x_0) = d(v)\}$. We need to show that $X = V$. Suppose not, then $Y := V \setminus X \neq \emptyset$.

Take $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$. Since $d(x)\neq d(y)$, $x$ and $y$ must be adjacent by point 1). Hence :
$$\forall x \in X, \, \forall y \in Y, \, (x,y)\in E$$
If either $X$ or $Y$ had only one element, then this element would have $n-1$ neighbours, which can't be. Hence, $X$ and $Y$ have at least two elements each.

Let us take distinct elements $x_1\neq x_2 \in X$ and $y_1\neq y_2\in Y$. Since $x_i \in N(y_1) \cap N(y_2), \ i=1,2$ we must have $x_1 = x_2$, a contradiction!

Comment: I'm probably just being dense, but I don't quite follow the second part.  I see that there's a $z_1$ not adjacent to $x$, and a $z_2$ not adjacent to $y$, but why can we take $z_1=z_2$?

Comment: @saulspatz Indeed, I was too quick on the second part and my argument is **wrong**. I'll edit that!

Comment: @bof Why is every vertex in $X$ adjacent to every vertex in $Y$? I don't get it.

Comment: Non-adjacent vertices have the same degree (from part 1). The contrapositive of this is that vertices of different degrees must be adjacent. All vertices of $X$ have a different degree to vertices in $Y$ by definition.

Comment: Sure, well done sir!

Comment: @bof I slightly changed your argument, but all credits go to you. :)

Comment: @OlivierRoche It's a good thing you changed it, it was kind of silly the way I wrote it. In case you're wondering why I made it needlessly complicated at the end: I misread the problem, confused it with a similar but different problem I'd seen before, and I thought the assumption was "for any two **nonadjacent** vertices there is a unique vertex joined to both of them." Now that I think about it, I don't see how to do part 1 from that weaker assumption, though I don't see a counterexample either.