# Prove that G is a regular graph if any two distinct vertices have zero or five neighbors

Tags: graph-theory

In the connected graph G, any two distinct vertices have zero or five neighbors in common. Prove that G is a regular graph.

Comment: It would be appropriate if you would specify where and how this question arose.

Comment: There are several similar questions on MSE, such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2798014/every-two-vertices-have-two-common-neighbors), 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3652599/proof-a-graph-where-any-two-vertices-have-exactly-two-common-neighbours-is-regul),
and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3369465/graph-where-any-two-vertices-have-unique-neighbor-in-common-must-be-regular).